# convert doc to pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, curl, doc

I need to convert doc file in pdf format
for that I am following saaspose functions mentioned below
(http://api.saaspose.com/v1.0/words/help)
I am not getting an error and a garbage file is uploaded along with doc file but I need to upload pdf file with same doc contents.

```
 private function convertDocToPdf($inputFileName,$outputFileName)
            {
                $doc = new WordDocument("");//Word document is a class to create new document
                $result = $doc->ConvertLocalFile($inputFileName, $outputFileName,"pdf");

            }

private function ConvertLocalFile($input_path, $output_path, $output_format) {
        try {
            $str_uri = "http://api.saaspose.com/v1.0/words/convert?format=" + $output_format;
            $signed_uri = Sign($str_uri);
            $responseStream = uploadFileBinary($signed_uri, $input_path, "xml");

            $v_output = ValidateOutput($responseStream);

            if ($v_output === "") {
                if ($output_format == "html")
                    $save_format = "zip";
                else
                    $save_format = $output_format;


                saveFile($responseStream,$outputFilename);
                return "";
            }
            else
                return $v_output;
        } catch (Exception $e) { 
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

 public static function saveFile($input, $fileName){
            $fh = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            fwrite($fh, $input);
            fclose($fh);
        }


public static function Sign($UrlToSign) {
        // parse the url
        $url = parse_url($UrlToSign);

        if (isset($url['query']) == "")
            $urlPartToSign = $url['path'] . "?appSID=" . 1fc17cb5-6c47-462e-9dfd-d1a9525220fa;
        else
            $urlPartToSign = $url['path'] . "?" . str_replace(" ","%20",$url["query"]) . "&appSID=" . SaasposeApp::$AppSID;


        // Decode the private key into its binary format
        $decodedKey = self::decodeBase64UrlSafe(87c027855aebf72e204b3bcd710de1c0);


        // Create a signature using the private key and the URL-encoded
        // string using HMAC SHA1. This signature will be binary.
        $signature = hash_hmac("sha1", $urlPartToSign, $decodedKey, true);

        $encodedSignature = self::encodeBase64UrlSafe($signature);

        if (isset($url['query']) == "")
            return $url["scheme"] . "://" . $url["host"] . str_replace(" ", "%20",$url["path"]) . "?appSID=" . 1fc17cb5-6c47-462e-9dfd-d1a9525220fa  . "&signature=" . $encodedSignature;
        else
            return $url["scheme"] . "://" . $url["host"] . str_replace(" ", "%20",$url["path"]) . "?" . str_replace(" ","%20",$url["query"]) . "&appSID=" . 1fc17cb5-6c47-462e-9dfd-d1a9525220fa . "&signature=" . $encodedSignature;
    }

public static function uploadFileBinary($url, $localfile, $headerType="XML") {

        $headerType = strtoupper($headerType);
        $fp = fopen($localfile, "r");

        $session = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

        if ($headerType == "XML") {
            curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml', 'Content-Type: application/xml'));
        } else {
            curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        }
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));


        $result = curl_exec($session);
        //$error = curl_error($session);
        //$http_code = curl_getinfo($session, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($session);
        fclose($fp);
        return $result;
    }

public static function ValidateOutput($result)
    {
        $string = (string)$result;

        $validate = array("Unknown file format.", "Unable to read beyond the end of the stream", 
        "Index was out of range", "Cannot read that as a ZipFile", "Not a Microsoft PowerPoint 2007 presentation",
        "Index was outside the bounds of the array", "An attempt was made to move the position before the beginning of the stream",
        );

        $invalid = 0;
        foreach ($validate as $key => $value) {
            $pos = strpos($string, $value);

            if ($pos === 1)
            {
                $invalid = 1;
            }
        }

        if($invalid == 1)
           return $string;
        else
           return "";
    }
```

Kindly provide me the solution because this error hampers my work terribly.

Comment: What uri is stored in $signed_uri?

Comment: edited and mentioned uri

Comment: The correct URI states http://api.saaspose.com/v1.0/words/convert?format={FORMAT}&appSID={APPSID}. Your URI doens't contain an appSID?

Comment: what should be appSID??
When I download the app of saaspose they have mentioned appSID=""

Kindly suggest me what need to be done

Comment: On http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordscloud/1.4%20-%20Saaspose.Words%20REST%20Live%20Examples it says "In the URI column above we've left out the appSID and signature parameters, just to make the examples easier to follow. You add these parameters to authenticate your requests." Without these parameters you can't authenticate to their service. Can't you find them on you account at their website?

Comment: Sir,now I have append my full code.Kindly have thr review and I am seeking forward for a help